# Angular can't load JSON data provided by Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json, api

In my Rails backend I have this method to fetch data from database and make json out of it:

```
  def index
    @airports = Airport.select('id,city,country')
    render status:200, json: { airports: @airports }
  end
```

And in my routes I have this method call:

```
  resources :airports
```

And when I wisit `localhost:3000/airports` I get a JSON wall of text.

Now when I try to load that JSON from my Angular controller I get error that is shown in screenshot below: (browser console)

[image]

This is my controller:

```
AppControllers.controller('DepartureLocationCtrl', [
  '$scope','$http',
  function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('localhost:3000/airports').success(function(data){
      $scope.departureLocations = data;
    });
  }
]);
```

I understand that controller is not place for this, so how would I fix this error and use factory instead?

Comment: Is that exception is coming from your browser?

Comment: @AnthonyE Yes it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't use `http://` in path.

**Edit:** Good catch by @Charlie Brown, now I only used `/airports` in path and it works good.

```
AppControllers.controller('DepartureLocationCtrl', [
  '$scope','$http',
  function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('/airports').success(function(data){
      $scope.departureLocations = data;
    });
  }
]);
```

Comment: Note, you can also take out the "localhost:3000" part and just do `$http.get('/airports')`. The reason it failed was it thought `localhost:3000` was a special protocol (like http is a protocol)